# File Not Found when trying to create a PrintWriter, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to edit a file in internal storage (So no permission should be needed, right?), but when I run this code:

```
String locus = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            File locusfile = new File(locus);
            String loglocation = locus + "/log.txt";
            File log = new File(loglocation);

            if(log.exists())
            {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(log);

            }
```

the PrintWriter pw comes up with "FileNotFoundException".

Why would this occur even when I verify that the file exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `log.createNewFile();` after `File log = new File(loglocation);`.

Comment: I am not sure why, but this brings up an IOexception

Comment: That is weird, I just tested it. What's the IOException .getMessage()? Could there be a folder named log.txt?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I have been busy

I can't find out because the file won't compile in android studio, and it seems like IOException.getMessage() doesn't exist?

Sorry, i'm new to app development.

Thanks

Comment: oh, I figured it out, but it just displays:
java.io.IOException